# binding different DNS to one DNS - iis 7 - programmatically

Tags: windows, iis-7, web, dns

I have multiple sites -

> www.ca1.com

,

> ca1.com

. All these sites are to be bind to

> www.mysite.com/ca1

programmatically on IIS 7.

Comment: sorry to ask, but ... why ? DNS changes can take a long time to spread, in the meanwhile you'd still resolve to the old destination.

Comment: actually, I would like this, when a user types www.ca1.com it should be redirected to www.mysite.com/ca1. we can do the same thing in IIS Manager through site bindings option. I guess, you got problem now. Pls let me know if you need some more info.thanks

Comment: i think you'll find solutions posting this on serverfault, i don't think it can be done programmatically in a meaningful way

Answer (score 0):

We can implement URL Rewrite. please go through below link.

http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Otherwise we can handle this in Router level of network.

Comment: I have seen the link provided. Here it is rewriting the URL not redirecting. I guess, you can do rewriting on the same domain name and not possible to rewrite URL to another domain name.

Comment: yes yes, it won't work. sorry. let me think how we can do this.